# how to put an image / logo at the middle positions

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I've been struggling to put an image / logo in the middle.

I did at the inspect id did nothing. From center - align middle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NewaR.png)

Comment: Can you update your question with appropriate code means issue reproducible code

Comment: Your question needs more details. You should add codes snippets instead of attaching screenshots. I'm only guessing, you can try adding `display: block;margin: auto;` to the `img` you're trying to make center positioned.

Comment: ok wait a minute

Comment: Hi Jhodi, here's how you produce a [reprex]. Furthermore, you can center almost any element (given a specific size and available space) horizontally with `{ margin: 0 auto }`

Answer (score 0):

You can add to image container `display: flex`
then you should add for image `margin: auto`